# Add partitioning to mysql built with no partitioning support

Tags: mysql, installation, database-partitioning

Found this question but there is no proper answer, so asking again.
How do we add partitioning support in mysql if its not built/installed with it.Please note that the version supports partitioning but its not specified at installation time.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to obtain a copy of MySQL which was compiled with partitioning support. It can't be added on "after the fact".